# awk: how to remove duplicated lines in a file and output them in another file at the same time?

Tags: bash, csv, awk, uniq

I am currently working on a script which processes csv files, and one of the things it does is remove and keep note of duplicate lines in the files. My current method to do this is to run uniq once using uniq -d once to display all duplicates, then run uniq again without any options to actually remove the duplicates.
Having said that, I was wondering if it would be possible to perform this same function in one action instead of having to run uniq twice. I've found a bunch of different examples of using awk to remove duplicates out there, but as far as I know I have not been able to find any that both displayed the duplicates and removed them at the same time.
If anyone could offer advice or help for this I would really appreciate it though, thanks!

Comment: Stock answer to all text manipulation questions: yes, it is trivial in awk. Now - what is it you want to do? Post some small sample input, the expected output after running the desired tool on that input and an explanation of why that would be the output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's something to get you started:

```
awk 'seen[$0]++{print|"cat>&2";next}1' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

The above will print any duplicated lines to stderr at the same time as removing them from your input file. If you need more, tell us more....

Answer (score 1):

In general, the size of you input shall be your guide. If you're processing GBs of data, you often have no choice other than relying on `sort` and `uniq`, because these tools support [external](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) operations.

That said, here's the AWK way:

- If you input is sorted, you can keep track of duplicate items in AWK easily by comparing line `i` to line `i-1` with *O(1)* state: if `i == i-1` you have a duplicate.
- If your input is not sorted, you have to keep track of *all* lines, requiring *O(c)* state, where *c* is the number of unique lines. You can use a hash table in AWK for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not use `awk` but it does produce the result you need.  In the command below replace sortedfile.txt with your csv file.

```
cat sortedfile.txt | tee >(uniq -d > duplicates_only.txt) | uniq > unique.txt
```

`tee` sends the output of the `cat` command to `uniq -d`.

Comment: Lose the Useless Use of Cat, though.