# Print Date and Username from a secure log file

Tags: bash, awk, rhel

I'm trying to get the Username and Date `'y/m/d'` from a `/var/log/secure`, however when I'm trying to use `awk`, it only provides the date.

Sample of a secure log file.

```
2022-11-23T02:03:24.594880+01:00 servername su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user john.doe by (uid=0)
```

What I'm expecting to print is: `2022-11-23 john.doe`

Here's my code.

```
cat /var/log/secure | grep 'session opened' | awk -FT '{print $1 " " " User: " $9 }'
```

"The output is only: `2022-11-23  User:"`

Comment: Regarding using `T` as a field separator - that would go badly if you every wanted to find `Tom.Jones` in your log file, can you not have upper case letters in names in your log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the `T` char as the field separator.

That gives you 2 fields where field 1 is `2022-11-23` and after that you print  `User:`

---

What you might do is use either 1 or more spaces or `T` as a field separator and then print field 1 and field 10:

```
 awk -F"[[:blank:]]+|T" '{print $1, $10 }' file
```

Another option could be splitting the first field on `T` instead of the whole line and then print the first part followed by field 9:

```
awk '{split($1,a,"T"); print a[1], $9}'
```

Or matching the date like pattern followed by a `T` and then print the match without the `T` followed by field 9:

```
awk 'match($0, /^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}T/) {
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1), $9
}'
```

**Output**

```
2022-11-23 john.doe
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -F'T| user | by '  '{print $1,$3}' Input_file
```

Comment: Really useful to know multiple field separators can act at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

With the assumption that the `date` always comes first and the `username` is in between the strings `user` and `by`
A `sed` solution would be something like:

```
sed '/session opened/s/^\([^T]*\).* user \(.*\) by .*$/\1 \2/' /var/log/secure
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for `cat` or `grep`:

```
$ awk '/session opened/{print substr($0,1,10), $9}' /var/log/secure
2022-11-23 john.doe
```

You never need `grep` when you're using awk. `grep 'session opened' | awk '{foo}'` = `awk '/session opened/{foo}'`, and you never need `cat` just to open a file, see https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.

Comment: Love this one, easy to understand, is it possible to append the output to a file without duplicate entry?.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to append this to a file. Like

awk '/session opened/{print substr($0,1,10), $9}' /var/log/secure |  awk '!seen[$0]++' >> secure_finals.txt

But when I run that command again.. It will now duplicate the entries. 
I need to put it in cron and will run everyday.

Comment: Oh, you're so great sir, I found an answer on this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632831/awk-how-to-remove-duplicated-lines-in-a-file-and-output-them-in-another-file-at

and you're also the one who answer it correctly, I tried your command.

awk '/session opened/{print substr($0,1,10), $9}' /var/log/secure |  awk '!seen[$0]++' >> secure_finals.txt > tmp && mv tmp secure_finals.txt

but it always asking me to overwrite a file which should not.

Comment: What do you think of this command? to overwrite a file without entering 'y'.

awk '/session opened/{print substr($0,1,10), $9}' /var/log/secure |  awk '!seen[$0]++' >> secure_finals.txt > tmp && yes | mv tmp secure_finals.txt

Is that good ? or we can make it more easily and more cleaner?

Comment: [Chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged on this forum, just ask a new question.